# query in relation 1:m on neo4j - graphql

Tags: neo4j, graphql, neo4j-ogm

I am new working with neo4j, I have a node that has a relation of type 'TYPE_OF' with other 2 nodes, when I execute the following query:`match(e:Event)-[:TYPE_OF]->(t:Tag) where e.type="ACL.SINGUP" and e.subtype="Birth" return e,t` returns the expected result[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1epAQ.png)

however, when I run the same query from graphql I only get one node from the relationship instead of the two. This is the query in graphql: `call graphql.query("{Event(type:\"ACL.SINGUP\", subtype:\"Birth\"){_id,data,typeOf {_id,owner,name}}}")` [graphql result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf5o6.png)

Comment: Can you check the generated Cypher query? It should be in the Neo4j log.

Comment: in the logs folder there is only debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is `typeOf` collection type in graphql schema def ?

```
e.g.
`type Event {
 _id: ID,
 data: String,
 typeOf: [TypeOf] 
}
type TypeOf {
 _id: ID,
 owner: String,
 name: String
}`
```

Comment: How can I see the query that is generated from my graphql query?

Comment: can you pls post resolver code and Event schema ?  I don't think so any problem in Cypher, as it's very simple query.

Comment: Schema:
`
Tag(
_id: Long
_ids: [Long]
first: Int
offset: Int): [Tag]
Event(
_id: Long
_ids: [Long]
first: Int
offset: Int): [Event]
`

I do not know my resolver

Comment: This looks diff than your original question. typeDef should be like from my first post (as I understood from your question). I don't see `typeOf` in your schema

Comment: I'm using the default scheme, I think it's related to this: [declare 'multi' property in graphql-Neo4j schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139200/declare-multi-property-in-graphql-neo4j-schema) 

The typeOf does not appear in the schema, however it is a relation between Event and Tag, because it appears in the graphiQL autocompletion

Comment: This may help you
https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql
    `CALL graphql.schema()` and then 
    `CALL graphql.idl('schema-text')`